# install pyspark in EC2 instance (amazon linux)

Tags: amazon-ec2, pyspark

Hi I tried to install pyspark in a EC2 instance (standard Amazon linux image). I installed anaconda python 3.6 and used "pip install pyspark" to install spark. It worked just fine. But when I try to enter pyspark with command "pyspark", I got the following error message. What could have gone wrong? Thanks!

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/03/03 05:47:13 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/03/03 05:47:13 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 45, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 273, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:546)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 10-236-108-194: 10-236-108-194: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:891)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:884)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:884)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:941)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 10-236-108-194: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
        ... 23 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 54, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 273, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:546)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Docker container: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook why go thru the hassle of configuring it?